# Python module "pyLDAvis.gensim" not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, python-module

I installed `pyLDAvis` and `gensim` modules in jupyter notebook, when I tried to use `"pyLDAvis.gensim"` module I am getting an error as:

```
No "module named 'pyLDAvis.gensim'"
```

Please find the detailed error below:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-ef16c68ef524> in <module>
     12 # libraries for visualization
     13 import pyLDAvis
---> 14 import pyLDAvis.gensim
     

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyLDAvis.gensim'
```

Any idea why I am getting this error even after installing those individual modules

Do let me know if any additional information is required.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Update the package to:

```py
import pyLDAvis.gensim_models
```

instead of using:

```py
import pyLDAvis.gensim
```

Comment: The OP mentions that they already tried that and it didn't work.